# Switching between tabs and frames

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So i have this website : **http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp**
I need to enter the IEC code and Bank IFSC codes and then a captcha.

**IEC codes :**

1. 0392032449
2. 0906008051

**IFSC code :**

1. HDFC0000102
2. DEUT0797TRS

Later i get a new tab( after i gave sendkeys ctrl+Enter), with a table with  **Print** options(total 200), i need to click on them and save them on my system one by one.

**Issues**

1. I thought i can click on print option with CTrl+Enter so that it opens in a new tab and then i can click enter to save the file as Chrome auto save option pops up.
2. The Chrome auto save PDF file opens and then i can't search for elements as the inspection tools says"it out of frame".

**Someone please look into this and help me out.**

So far my code:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub downloadpdf()

Dim bot As WebDriver
Dim keys As New Selenium.keys
Dim count As Long

Set bot = New WebDriver
bot.Start "Chrome"
bot.Get "http://dgftebrc.nic.in:8100/BRCQueryTrade/index.jsp"

count = 1
While (Len(Range("A" & count)) > 0)

bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='iec']").SendKeys Range("A" & count)
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='ifsc']").SendKeys Range("B" & count)

bot.Wait 10000         'Time to enter the Captcha

bot.FindElementByCss("[value='Show Details']").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow



bot.FindElementByXPath("//tr[2]//td[11]//form[1]//font[1]//input[4]").SendKeys keys.Control, keys.Enter
bot.SwitchToNextWindow

'bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='sidebar']//print-preview-button-strip//cr-button[1]").SendKeys keys.Enter

bot.Window.Close
'bot.Window.Close


bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.SwitchToPreviousWindow
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='iec']").Clear
bot.FindElementByXPath("//input[@name='ifsc']").Clear



count = count + 1
Wend
bot.Quit
End Sub
```

[image: See Image for more reference]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I could not see any print option in the usl you have shared , below are 2 ways to save pdf from chrome when no download button or option is not given but.

```
# if any pdf tab opens in chrome during the session that will be auto downloaded

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe", options=options)




## 2 if you want to save after sending print to chrome window

appState = {
    "recentDestinations": [
        {
            "id": "Save as PDF",
            "origin": "local",
            "account": ""
        }
    ],
    "selectedDestinationId": "Save as PDF",
    "version": 2
}

profile = {'printing.print_preview_sticky_settings.appState': json.dumps(appState)}

opt=webdriver.ChromeOptions()
system_user =getpass.getuser()
opt.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
opt.add_argument("--start-maximized")
# Required for printing
opt.add_experimental_option('prefs', profile)
opt.add_argument('--kiosk-printing')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe", options=opt)

driver.get(www.google.com)
# below line will come post the winow you want to save is visible
driver.execute_script('window.print();')
```

Comment: There is a "Print" button in my scenario.
That needs to be clicked which pops up a separate tab and then there the automatic Chrome Pdf reader opens and asks to save as ".PDF".
It is there i can't take access as it is out of frame.

Comment: how can i reach that print button , as in the link which you have shared no print button there. .. and if pdf opens in new tab first approach should work.. i will try to search some example link

Comment: Hi Sir, as soon as you click on submit button, there's a page with so many rows and then a "Print" option against each row.
I have added the image too now.
Sorry for the delay, i was not keeping well.

Comment: @AmitShah give me some sample data to be used

Comment: Hi Sir, the sample data was already present in the question, now i have edited it, thought it was on non-readable format.
Now you can have a look at it.